# How can I explain this drop in performance on test data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am asking the question here, even though I hesitated to post it on CrossValidated (or DataScience) StackExchange. I have a dataset of 60 labeled objects (to be used for training) and 150 unlabeled objects (for test). The aim of the problem is to predict the labels of the 150 objects (this used to be given as a homework problem). For each object, I computed 258 features. Considering each object as a sample, I have `X_train : (60,258)`, `y_train : (60,)` (labels of the objects used for training) and `X_test : (150,258)`. Since the solution of the homework problem was given, I also have the *true* labels of the 150 objects, in `y_test : (150,)`.

In order to predict the labels of the 150 objects, I choose to use a LogisticRegression (the Scikit-learn implementation). The classifier is trained on `(X_train, y_train)`, after the data has been normalized, and used to make predictions for the 150 objects. Those predictions are compared to `y_test` to assess the performance of the model. For reproducibility, I copy the code I have used.

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, crosss_val_predict

# Fit classifier
LogReg = LogisticRegression(C=1, class_weight='balanced')
scaler = StandardScaler()
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogReg)
LogReg.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Performance on training data
CV_score = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc')
print(CV_score)

# Performance on test data
probas = LogReg.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
AUC = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, probas)
print(AUC)
```

The matrices `X_train`,`y_train`,`X_test` and `y_test` are saved in a .mat file available at [this link](https://file.town/download/oze8o0f9izj0c0p4xunqyzkaf). My problem is the following :

Using this approach, I get a good performance on training data (CV_score = 0.8) but the performance on the test data is much worse : AUC = 0.54 for C=1 in LogReg and AUC = 0.40 for C=0.01. How can I get AUC<0.5 if a naive classifier should score AUC = 0.5 ? Is this due to the fact that I have a small number of samples for training ?
I have noticed that the performance on test data improves if I change the code for :

```
y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, X_test, y_test, cv=5) 
AUC = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(AUC)
```

Indeed, AUC=0.87 for C=1 and 0.9 for C=0.01. Why is the AUC score so much better using cross validation predictions ? Is it because cross validation allows to make predictions on subsets of the test data which do not contain objects/samples which decrease the AUC ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are encountering an overfitting problem, i.e. the classifier trained using the training data is overfitting to the training data. It has poor generalization ability. That is why the performance on the testing dataset isn't good.

`cross_val_predict` is actually training the classifier using part of your testing data and then predict on the rest. So the performance is much better.

Overall, there seems to be quite some difference between your training and testing datasets. So the classifier with the highest training accuracy doesn't work well on your testing set.

Another point not directly related with your question: since the number of your training samples is much smaller than the feature dimensions, it may be helpful to perform dimension reduction before feeding to classifier.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your training and test process are inconsistent. Although from your code you intend to standardize your data, you fail to do so during testing. What I mean:

`clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogReg)
LogReg.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Although you define a pipeline, you do not fit the pipeline (`clf.fit`) but only the Logistic Regression. This matters, because your cross-validated score is calculated with the pipeline (`CV_score = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc')`) but during test instead of using the pipeline as expected to predict, you use only `LogReg`, hence the test data are not standardized.

The second point you raise is different. In `y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, X_test, y_test, cv=5)`
 you get predictions by doing cross-validation on the test data, while ignoring the train data. Here, you do data standardization since you use `clf` and thus your score is high; this is evidence that the standardization step is important.

To summarize, standardizing the test data, I believe will improve your test score.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it makes no sense to have 258 features for 60 training items. Secondly CV=10 for 60 items means you split the data into 10 train/test sets. Each of these has 6 items only in the test set. So whatever results you obtain will be useless. You need more training data and less features.